# Invalid availability zone [eu-west-1a] returned by describe_spot_price_history

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS Ruby SDK, and I'm stack with an error message returned by describe_spot_price_history. The error message says: **Invalid availability zone : eu-west-1a**

This message is returned only for availability zones in europe (eu-west-1a...) and not for other zone in us-east. Do you have any idea how to solve this issue ? Thank you !

Here is my ruby script :

```
begin
  ec2 = AWS::EC2.new(
    :access_key_id => access_key,
    :secret_access_key => access_secret)

  response = ec2.client.describe_spot_price_history(
    :start_time => start_time,
    :end_time => end_time,
    :instance_types => instance_type,
    :product_descriptions => 'Linux/UNIX',
    :availability_zone => availability_zone
  )

  prices = Array.new(response.spot_price_history_set.map(&:spot_price))
  prices = prices.flatten.collect { |i| i.to_f }
  puts prices

rescue
  puts "Error: " + $!
  exit 1
end
```

Comment: I think you need to change `:ec2_endpoint` in `AWS::config` to the [eu-west regional endpoint,](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region) but I'm not certain enough to post it as an answer. More details about config options [here.](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html)

Comment: It works! thank you Christopher :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the ec2 end point parameter to EC2.new

```
  ec2 = AWS::EC2.new(
    :access_key_id => access_key,
    :secret_access_key => access_secret,
    :ec2_endpoint => 'ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com')
```